# Help or advice UV Unwrapping/UV Mapping this object

Tags: uv

I am having a lot of difficulty and many hours wasted trying to UV unwrap the lower section of my window and I am not sure why, I am wondering can anyone help in knowing what the best and simplest way to UV unwrap this shape would be. After I UV map it I want to create a 2d texture in gimp.

Have tried the normal way of using seams to get this result

[image: UV Unwrap lower section of window1]
[image]

I have tried to reset UV's to then use cube projection and then follow active quads totally unusable for what I want.

[image: UV reset, cube projection, follow active quads]

Old version I tried various UV unwrapping method, sometimes I have way too many UV islands
[image: UV old too many islands]

Old version here are just too many islands and deformed shape
[image]

The best result so far is the normal UV unwrap with seams, (the 1st,2nd pic) but the results are not great for what I want, the shape is totally deformed, and I don’t understand why that is. The topology of this shape maybe is wrong and that is why it won’t unwrap correctly and is deformed? but it is just really a cube, so I don’t understand.

Does anyone have any idea in a simple way in how to UV unwrap it correctly, maybe blender is missing some important UV tools, that I just don't have or know about I must be missing something.

this is my blend file one drive.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuAaTBGM4OEw80dpaMtBypYn5TfP?e=ODDePm

If any advice please make it so I can reproduce your results, I am a beginner.

## Update2

Hi Robin Betts, yes I should clarify what this is for.

This model is to be imported into source 1 an old game engine that can still look decent, if taken time to create assets.
So, I will be using a 2D texture sheet created in gimp or some art program after UV unwrap and there can’t be any overlapping UV’s.
Texture size maybe 1024x1024 or 2048x2048 the main comb_window_frame is already UV Unwrapped it should be in the blend file.
The comb_window_low1 is what is causing me the problems.

How do I want to shade the ridges?
Okay I will try to give an idea, yes, I want the ridges to have shadows, I done a very quick mockup of what I want the texture to look like here.
I baked ambient occlusion and layered a basic texture over it

[image]
[image]

I also have my reference model here.
[image]

Now I just need to get a good unwrap

So clarify again the comb_window_low1 will use a texture of 1024x1024 pixles maybe 2048x2048 probably not

the comb_window_frame will also use a seperate 1024x1024 maybe 2048x2048 probably not

the comb_window_cover will share one of the texture sheets above

the comb_glass will use maybe 64x64 the refence model above only uses 16x16 and looks great to me so maybe might use that

I also don't want mirror modifier of the texture so the unwrap should accommodate for 2 of everything regarding the comb_window_lower1. Oh and no overlapping UV's like here I can't work with that when creating a 2D texture.

[image]

So my question is, is there a simple way to get a good clean unwrap so I can create a clean 2D texture in gimp or other art program any help would be great thanks.

## Update 3

So this is what I am going with right now, I UV unwrapped it in sections, a lot of UV islands and for 2D texturing not great really or ideal.  I am just wondering is there a better way.

Thanks Robin Betts no it is not wood, the window frame is made out of some type of metal.

[image]

Comment: Had a look.. this will partly depend on the nature of your texture, IMO. How do you want to shade the ridges? Can you give us an idea of what you want them to look like, in the end?

Comment: Hi, Robin Betts, I updated my original post does that help in anyway

Comment: It sure is a tricky unwrap.. just checking .. is that a wood texture (maybe 3D procedural wood would be easier)? Do you have the option of modelling separate parts _as_ separate parts? (Does the ridged sill need to be a single manifold?)